# How to keep original user-entered value intact, while still being able to change it in the input field programmatically

Tags: jquery

How can I store user input using JS so that I can restore it later (i.e. via pressing a button).

Assume that the user enters text into an input field of a form, like so:

```
<form>
    <select name="unit_system" id="unit_system">
        <option value="English">English</option>
        <option value="Metric">Metric</option>  
    </select>

    <input class="input_gpm" type="text" value="<?=$value?>" />

</form>
```

I want to be able to revert to the originally-entered value, even if the value in the input field changes programmatically, as can happen when the value is converted from one unit system of measurements to another.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not just store the user input in its own variable? Using jQuery:

```
var $userInput;
$(".input_gpm").on("change", function(){
    $userInput = $(".input_gpm").val();
});
```

Then, as the user inputs a value into the select field, it gets stored in the $userInput variable for storage and future use. It then would get rewritten only when the user manually inputs text into the input field.

Answer (score 0):

Here's my attempt at it, could use a little cleaning up I'm sure. Same principle behind it as barrt's answer of storing an original value, but implemented the select option

```js
var origVal = $('#input_gpm').val();

$('#unit_system').change(function() {
  
  var selected = $(this).find('option:selected');
  
  if ( selected.val() === 'Metric' ) {
    // maths here
    var newVal = '18.927 lpm';
    $('#input_gpm').val(newVal)
  }
  
  if ( selected.val() === 'English' ) {
   $('#input_gpm').val(origVal)
  }
  
  
  
  $('#output-origVal').html('origVal: ' + origVal)
  $('#output-newVal').html('newVal: ' + newVal)
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<form>
  <select name="unit_system" id="unit_system">
    <option value="English">English</option>
    <option value="Metric">Metric</option>  
  </select>

  <input id="input_gpm" type="text" value="5 gpm" />

</form>
  
<hr>
  
<div id="output-origVal"></div>
<div id="output-newVal"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You may use a hidden input field inside the form itself and change the value of that hidden field to the absolute value when the user submits the form. If you don't use a hidden field and just update the input value, then there is a chance of user seeing the value is changed when submitting and the user may be confused...

HTML:

```
<form id="formId" action="">
    <input type="hidden" name="absolute_value" id="absolute_value"/>
    <select name="unit_system" id="unit_system">\
        <option value="English">English</option>
        <option value="Metric">Metric</option>  
    </select>

    <input class="input_gpm" type="text" value="<?=$value?>" />
    <button type='submit'>submit</button>
</form>
```

Jquery/js:

```
$('#formId').submit(function(){
    var value =  $(".input_gpm").val();
    var option = $("#unit_system").val();
    //conversion to absolute value
    $('#absolute_value').val(absoluteValue);
});
```

Then use the value from hidden field from server side.

Answer (score 0):

Great answers here as to how to do exactly what I asked... but I ended up tearing out that logic from my code and putting it into PHP instead.  Thus, making my view (HTML, JS) not aware of conversions or saving and restoring values, and my back-end logic more conversion and save/restore-aware.